# "Conscribed" vs "conscripted"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences

I'm wondering about the usage of the words *conscript* and *conscribe* in terms of the meaning they share.

I went to use the word *conscripted* as in "conscripted for duty", and the word *conscribe* also came to mind, and I wasn't sure which to use. Looking around it seems like *conscribe* isn't used much and isn't in all dictionaries. Is it an outdated version of the same word from Latin?

Also, what about the preposition? I see instances of both "conscripted into" and "conscripted for" in Google results. Is there a difference?

Comment: Conscript reporting!

Comment: I'd never even heard `conscribe` before but I think it's great.  I'm going to ditch `conscript` (as a verb anyway, it also means "draftee").

Comment: @Malvolio - It has a noble history too: the Roman Senate were called "Conscript Fathers"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to the main point of your question, you should use 'conscript', since 'conscribe' actually has two meanings, and is not nearly as common. (This spell checker doesn't even recognize it!)

The preposition could be equally either.  'Conscripted into the army' makes just as much grammatical sense as 'conscripted for the army', although the latter puts a slightly higher emphasis on the 'army' than does the former; just because 'for' is more of a Preposition Of Interest, and draws one's attention to its object more than 'into' might.